# jQuery Force fadeIn() to use display: block for list items

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am using fadeIn() to fade in some list items. I want them to go from `display: none` to `display: block`.

But jQuery applies the style `list-item` instead of `block`.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kDCwJ/

Currently I am doing the following to compensate but I think there must be a cleaner way:

```
$('li').fadeIn().css({ display: 'block' });
```

Is there a way to force fadeIn() to result in `display: block` styling for `<li>` elements?

Thanks!

Comment: No, what you're doing is the cleanest way assuming you don't want to add _any_ CSS.

Comment: Sure is -> http://jsfiddle.net/kDCwJ/1/

Comment: its probably because it is picking up the element type: `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not while it's a `list-item` itself. If you want `display:block` you can use a `div` element which will `fadeIn` to `display:block`.

Note that using `display:block` on your list-item makes some of the list-item properties go away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS make the list item say Display Block... then with your inline CSS make it say display none. that way it kinda sets "Block" as the default type of display to return to when fading in.

css: `display:block;`

html:  `li style="display:none;">I'm a list item</li>`

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/znv09u4c/